# Android application with some c code and cross-platform issue

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, cross-platform

see i have refereed http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html

and make a java application using some sort of c code by jni now when ever i compile this package and get the .apk of that application.

But now my question is that here if have cross-compile c code for arm platform then this .apk will work on only arm platform right? it will not work on other platform's android machine?

Now if i need to make this .apk as platform independent then how can i make that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://source-android.frandroid.com/ndk/docs/APPLICATION-MK.html, you should put the line `APP_ABI := all` in your `Application.mk`, and than it will compile your code separately for each platform that support android.

(For only some platforms, you can write something like `APP_ABI := armeabi x86`)

Comment: you means in final .apk it will have multiple .so or binary for used c code. and if i install that .apk in ARM machine then ARM's binary or.so will be used and if i install that .apk in MIPS then MIPS's binary or ,so will be used... ?

Comment: Note that the official NDK http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html supports ARM and x86:

    ARMv5TE (including Thumb-1 instructions)
    ARMv7-A (including Thumb-2 and VFPv3-D16 instructions, with optional support for NEON/VFPv3-D32 instructions)
    x86 instructions (see CPU-ARCH-ABIS.HTML for more information)

To add MIPS support, you should go for http://developer.mips.com/android/download-android-ndk/.